# How to ADD A SUB-QUERY in MYSQL query?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, inner-join

I have a table TBLCUTOMERS with following fields:

```
- cutomerid
- customername
- customerphone
```

I have another table TBLTRANSACTIONS with following fields:

```
- transactionid
- customerid (foreign key to table above)
- transactiondetail
- transactionamount
```

I have a query to get all transactions from tbltransactions:

```
 "select * from tbltransactions";
```

How could I a sub-query in it such that I GET CUSTOMERNAME FROM TBLCUSTOMERS AGAINST EACH CUSTMERID IN THE ABOVE QUERY?

**Expecting output:**

```
- transactionid
- customername (from tblcustomers)
- transactiondetail
- transactionamount
```

Please Note, I am new to MySql. Thanks

Comment: You can use join query will that work ?? I mean if i give you a join query not a sub query will that be ok??

Comment: Sure! I am just interested in result.

Comment: Do you allow us to use JOIN?

Answer (score 1):

```
select tt.transactionid ,tc.customername,tt.transactiondetail,tt.transactionamount from tbltransactions tt,TBLCUTOMERS tc where tt.customerid=tc.cutomerid
```

I think this will solve your purpose. for your reference ckeck the [link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/603c6/1)

Answer (score 0):

Its not subquery, we use join for that purpose.

something like.

```
Select tt.*, c.customername 
from 
tbltransactions as tt
left join TBLCUTOMERS as c
on tt.customerid = c.customerid
```

And use left join or right join or inner join as per your required condition

Comment: why this outer join is required i don't get it.

Comment: as outer join is slightly faster than inner join

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT T.transactionid, C.customername, T.transactiondetail, T.transactionamount
FROM TBLTRANSACTIONS T 
INNER JOIN TBLCUTOMERS C ON T.cutomerid = C.cutomerid;
```